# Action Requested: Android app child-directed treatment?

Tags: android, admob

I recieved this from google play, what should I do ?

We’re contacting you because Google has received a report that your Android app(s) and package name(s) listed below may be child-directed for the purposes of the Children’s Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA). You can visit the Federal Trade Commission’s website to learn more about COPPA.

In 30 days, we will take the action to treat your app(s) listed below as primarily child-directed for applicable Google services that may appear in your app(s). For instance, this means AdMob will take steps to disable interest-based advertising and remarketing ads for your app(s).

If Google should NOT treat your app(s) as primarily child-directed (for example, because it is a mixed audience app), please click on the link(s) below to complete the form(s) by September 14, 2016.

Comment: I believe that it depends on what your Android app does.  If your game or app targets an audience that includes children under 13, you'll need to either not collect any personal data (and AdMob will refrain from doing so by disabling interest-based advertising), or get verifiable parental consent before collecting personal data.

Comment: my app is just simple, it's like a medicine alerte !! it doesn't collect any informations,

Comment: Then I believe then you need only mark your app as not being child-directed, or have ADMob disable interest-based advertising in your app.